# fade/opacity on scroll but disable when back to top using jQuery

Tags: jquery

```js
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100 || $('.header,.footer').css('opacity') ==1) {
        if($(window).width() > 478)
        {
            var elem = $('.header,.footer');
            setTimeout(function() {
                elem.css({"opacity":"0","transition":"2s"});
            },5000);            
            elem.css({"opacity":"1","transition":"1s"}); 
        } 
    } else {
       return false;
    }

});
```

```css
.header {top:0;position:fixed;width:100%;height:50px;background:red;}
.content {height:1500px;}
.footer {bottom:0;position:fixed;width:100%;height:50px;background:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
</head> 
<body>
<div class="header">
</div>
<div class="content">
</div>
<div class="footer">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is what I use to hide div elements:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
if($(window).width() > 1199)
{
    var elem = $('.header,.footer');
    setTimeout(function() {
        elem.css({"opacity":"0","transition":"2s"});
    },10000);            
    elem.css({"opacity":"1","transition":"1s"}); 
}   
});
```

I want to set something to disable this function when top=0, or set opacity to 1 when back to the top or something to not fade when at top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a check for how far the user has scrolled:

```
$(window).scroll(myController);

function myController() {
  if($(window).width() > 1199 && $(document).scrollTop() > 50) {

    var elem = $('.header,.footer');

    setTimeout(function() {
        elem.css({"opacity":"0","transition":"2s"});
    },10000);            

    elem.css({"opacity":"1","transition":"1s"}); 
  }   
}
```

Note1: you should debounce the scroll event, since it fires
very frequently. See a popular library like [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce) or a [custom](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function) implementation.

Note2: you should also cache your selectors (`$(window)` and `$('.header, .footer')`), since atm header and footer are being looked up on every scroll event.

Comment: Hi and Thank you for the answer. Im not sure if the reason is debounce, but when back to top script still working/cycling. .scrollTop() > 50) instruction working fine on start, also setTimeout(function() working fine while scrolling, but if scroll back to top the script still cycling, but I need something to stop functions (default opacity=1) Tried to turn off all other scripts, but no result

Comment: Could it be because of the long timeout value? In your original post, your code has a timeout of `10000` which is 10 seconds. If you reduce it (or remove it?), does the problem still remain when scrolling back to top?

Comment: yes, if set something like 4000,2000 even 200, nothing happen, if remove at all - not working even while scrolling. To be honest, was bad idea to hide with opacity, I will try with show/hide or something. Thank you for you time!

Answer (score 0):

you want to also check with opacity and top so you can use below.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 10 || $('.header,.footer').css('opacity') ==1) {
        if($(window).width() > 1199)
        {
            var elem = $('.header,.footer');
            setTimeout(function() {
                elem.css({"opacity":"0","transition":"2s"});
            },10000);            
            elem.css({"opacity":"1","transition":"1s"}); 
        } 
    } else {
       return false;
    }

});
```

Comment: Hi and Thank you. The same as above. When back to top ".scrollTop() > 10" instruction not working anymore and  "setTimeout(function()" still cycling, but I need to hide element only while scrolling, not when on the top

Comment: okay so you need to stop setTimeout(). you can set else condition in clearTimeout().

Comment: Trying.. 2h yet :) but no luck. I think something wrong with this method at all. Maybe .scrollTop() >.. and setTimeout.. could be in different func, I dont know. Anyway, thanks for you time. I will try something other, instead opacity hiding.